# HTACCESS rules redirection error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

In my htaccess file I have added a rule to redirect url/abc/xyz to url/abc/xyz.php so now even when I try to access url/abc.php it redirects me to url/abc/

Help me with this.. My code now :

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

What I want is :

> url/abc.php & url/abc should goto url/abc.php
>
> url/abc.php/#x & url/abc/#x should goto url/abc.php/#x

Comment: A 403 Forbidden error, as it tried to access a location that doesn't exist.

Comment: all located on the root.
http://domain.com/abc leads to http://domain.com/abc.php correctly. 
The problem is with http://domain.com/abc.php/#x which gets redirected to http://domain.com/abc/#x

Comment: why are you wanting url/abc.php to point to url/abc.php? Why not just eliminate the possibility of using .php in the address bar?

Comment: Yes, I shall eliminate .php completely but I was having it so that url/abc/#x (or url/abc.php/#x) gets redirected to url/abc.php/#x

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a 403 error and not a 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL fragment (#) is never sent to the server so you cannot use mod_rewrite to redirect it. In other words the # is only interpreted in the browser so you shouldn't need to worry about it in .htaccess.

This code should work for you, or at least get you started:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

I have also enclosed it in an IfModule to check to see if mod_rewrite is enabled first.

My preferred way, however, is to redirect everything to index.php and then have PHP code there that will break up the URLs and redirect to the appropriate pages. This works really well with Model-View-Controller (MVC) systems and other similar variants. This also allows general site settings to all be loaded from one place rather than many places. Here is the code that I would use for this type of setup:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+\.(gif|jpg|png)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+\.css$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+\.js$
  RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first three lines says to not redirect any images, css, or js files in the specified directories.

Comment: ok, is there any other way to achieve this? I am very new to htaccess.

Comment: @AniMenon I have edited my example a bit further. The first one should work for you but the second one is my preferred method.

Comment: Your second example is not safe, and will cause Rewrite loop error since /index.php also matches the rewrite pattern.

Comment: @starkeen I am currently implementing this on some of my sites and it seems to be working perfectly fine.

Comment: @kojow7 Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

If I've interpreted your intentions correctly, the following rewrite rules should serve your wishes:

```
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Define site root
RewriteBase /

# Do not rewrite for image, css or js files
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

# Add index.php to requests ending with a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-/]*/)?$ $1index.php [NC,R=301,L]

# Add .php to the end of a request without a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9_\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

What the rules do:

- Rewriting happens relatively to the root (/) of the domain
- Rewrite rules will ignore any file with a file extension listed in rule nr 2.
- Requests for `http://example.com/` (or `http://example.com`), `http://example.com/foo/` and `http://example.com/foo/bar/` will be rewritten to `http://example.com/index.php`, `http://example.com/foo/index.php` and `http://example.com/foo/bar/index.php` respectively
- Requests for `http://example.com/baz` and `http://example.com/baz/boo` will be rewritten to `http://example.com/baz.php` and `http://example.com/baz/boo.php` respectively